# How to fix the list strange padding when using navigationbaritems in swiftui since iOS 14?

Tags: swiftui, navigationview, ios14, navigationbaritems

Since iOS 14 i have a strange behavior where i have a padding around a list in a NavigationView as soon as i add navigationBarItems...

My code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestList: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      List {
        Text("hello world")
        Text("hello world")
        Text("hello world")
      }
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test List"), displayMode:.inline)
      .navigationBarItems(leading:
                            Image(systemName: "bell")
      )
    }
  }
}

struct TestList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    TestList()
  }
}
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok i got it...

I need to add a ListStyle to the list :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestList: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
      List {
        Text("hello world")
        Text("hello world")
        Text("hello world")
      }
      .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
      .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test List"), displayMode:.inline)
      .navigationBarItems(leading:
                            Image(systemName: "bell")
      )
    }
  }
}

struct TestList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    TestList()
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? As of 23 Nov 2020 Apple Dev's own SwiftUI tutorial omits this part, making it confusing for newcomers

Comment: Great answer man, I was banging my head